# UNION mysql determine which table the result came from

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM table1 UNION SELECT id FROM table2 UNION SELECT id FROM table3 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

The code above is my code for auto generating `ID`. I want to select the last inserted `ID`. What I want to do is I want to get the last ID inserted on three tables. It can be from any of the three tables. And then i want to increment that `ID`. But the catch is i need to know which table the last `ID` is from so i can select another field and record that the last `ID` has a certain attribute. This attribute is depending on the table that is why i want to get the table.

Comment: You need to use some updated_at or created_at column to determine which table has latest inserted records. You can not just determine based on value of ID you can just get table name which possess highest value of ID field.

Comment: probably max id ll be last inserted... or use mysqli_insert_id()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a discriminator column, and use the `MAX` aggregate function for each query to avoid sorting a huge intermediate resultset, and use `UNION ALL` set operator in place of `UNION` operator.  (Since each query will return only one row, that's not going to make much of a difference; but where we don't need to eliminate duplicate rows, we prefer the `UNION ALL` set operator to avoid the unnecessary (and sometimes expensive) operation.

Something like this should return the result you seem to be after:

```
( SELECT 'table1'   AS source
       , MAX(t1.id) AS max_id
    FROM table1 t1
)
UNION ALL
( SELECT 'table2'   AS source
       , MAX(t2.id) AS max_id
    FROM table2 t2
)
UNION ALL
( SELECT 'table3' AS source
     , MAX(t3.id) AS max_id
  FROM table3 t3
)
ORDER BY max_id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

That will give you a resultset that identifies the table name that had the maximum id.

NOTE: This assumes that the "last inserted id" is identified by the maximum value. If two tables have the same maximum id value, it's indeterminate which row will be returned. You can add `source` to the ORDER BY to make it deterministic:

```
ORDER BY max_id DESC, source DESC
```

(The actual requirements aren't clear to me; the statement above should return the same value that was being returned by the query in the question, along with a discriminator which tells which table the `id` value is from.)

Reference: [**https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html)

---

**NOTE:** This may satisfy your use case, but in the more general case, we advise *avoiding* this approach to get the id value of the row that was last inserted.

For values of an `auto_increment` column, where the value is automatically assigned, the `last_insert_id` function will return the id value of the first row that was inserted by the immediately preceding `INSERT` statement in the same session. In a multiuser system, it is *not* safe to assume that the "highest" id value was a row inserted by the current session - that approach is effectively broken.

Comment: sir the wayt to get the table is for example in pdo is like `$stmt->execute();
$selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $selected_row['source'];` please correct if i am wrong

Comment: there should not exist same `id` the last id should always be incremented sorry if my english is hard to understand

Comment: @HogRider:  Yes, you'd execute that SQL text (SELECT statement) and retrieve the results the same way you'd do it with any other SELECT statement, using PDO or any other library. I added cautionary notes to aid future readers of this question and answer. It sounds as if you have a specific use case, with some special constraints, and that may differ (significantly) from a more general use case where this approach would not be suitable.

Comment: With your explanation i think i can work on this i will study the sample you gave me and i will surely come up with something that is tailor fit to my needs . Idea is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to get last inserted ID  of  all  three  tables  and with inserted  time then  differentiate based on inserted time